# Stability shoes causes pain when running

Tags: running

I have flat feet, and I went to a store for shoes recommendation. The guy then recommended Mizuno Wave Rider and I'd been wearing that for a few years. Did a few marathon, weekly runs and so on.

As the Wave Rider was dying, I was looking for a replacement. This time round, the store told me that I'd been wearing the wrong shoes and a flat feet like me should wear Mizuno Inspire as it gives me more support. So I did, thinking the first guy made a mistake.

However, when I did the first run today, my feet hurt badly. It seemed like something was pushing the middle of my sole through out the run, and I couldn't even complete my run.

Is it normal for runners to feel like this when they change to a support/stability shoes? I don't really have any problem with Wave Rider, but the store said it will be bad for my knee, that's why I decided to change. Did I make a bad move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really get a second opinion on your foot shape, shoe required and probably speak to a physio.

The pain may just be from new muscles working with your new shoes style.  Your joints react to how your muscles are working so this could cause issues with your knees, back and ankles.

So if your new shoes are right, the short term pain will be better in the long run and go away but if the guy got it wrong, you could be doing serious damage.

Comment: Thanks. I will monitor the situation for a while and see how it goes.